# Load XML, apply XSL and append to existing HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, xml, iframe, htmlcollection

On an already loaded HTML page I want to load a XML file and append the resultig HTML to the loaded page. The XML file is linked with an XSL file. When I open it in the browser (Firefox) the XSL transformation is correctly applied. The result is HTML without html, head and body tags. That’s what I want.

Loading the XML with Ajax gives me the untransformed XML, not the HTML I wish.

My workaround so far is to load the XML file in a hidden iframe. In there the XSL transformation is correctly carried out.

I now fail to copy the HTML form the iframe and append it to an existing div in the page outside the iframe. I only manage to:

1. Get an HTML Collection (with jquery or plain JS):

```
iframe = $('#iframe');
iframeHtml = iframe.contents()[0].children;

iframe = document.getElementById('bausteine__liste__zwischenspeicher');
resultHtml = iframe.contentDocument || temp.contentWindow.document;
```

2. Get all HTML but only starting below the first div (with jquery). The uppermost div which contains everything is left out.

```
iframe = $('#iframe');
resultHtml = iframe.contents().find('div').html();
```

This is the iframe as I see it in the dev toolbar of Firefox

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="file-with-xslt.xml">
    <div class="uppermost-element">
        <div>
            …
        </div>
        <div>
            …
        </div>
    </div>
</iframe>
```

How can I get the HTML including the uppermost element? Either via the iframe or – even better – via Ajax.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to load both the XML and XSL with an XMLHttpRequest and to do the transformation with Javascript. `documentElement.outerHTML` will output the resulting HTML.

```
function XMLtransformation(xsl, xml) {

    var xslStylesheet;
    var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();                    
    var xmlDoc;                    
    
    // load XSL file
    var myXMLHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myXMLHTTPRequest.open('GET', urlXSL, false);
    myXMLHTTPRequest.send(null);
    
    xslStylesheet = myXMLHTTPRequest.responseXML;
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslStylesheet);
    
    // load XML file
    myXMLHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myXMLHTTPRequest.open('GET', urlXML, false);
    myXMLHTTPRequest.send(null);
    
    xmlDoc = myXMLHTTPRequest.responseXML;
    
    var htmlDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlDoc, document);

    return htmlDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;

}

XMLtransformation('file.xsl', 'file.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked [@Moritz's solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66580091/2860309), but it needed a bit of tweaking so here's my version:

```
function XMLtransformation(xslUrl, xmlUrl) {
    const errorMessage = 'Unable to load the content';
    const parser = new DOMParser();

    // attempt to load the XSL file
    const xslRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xslRequest.open('GET', xslUrl, false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
    xslRequest.send(null);

    if (xslRequest.status < 300) {
        const xslStylesheet = parser.parseFromString(xslRequest.response, "application/xml");
        const xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslStylesheet);

        const xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlRequest.open('GET', xmlUrl, false);
        xmlRequest.send(null);

        if (xmlRequest.status < 300) {
            const htmlDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(
                parser.parseFromString(xmlRequest.response, "application/xml"),
                document
            );

            return htmlDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
        } else {
            console.error('xml load failure:');
            console.error(xmlRequest.status, xmlRequest.responseText);
        }
    } else {
        console.error('xsl load failure:');
        console.error(xslRequest.status, xslRequest.responseText);
    }

    return errorMessage;
}
```